# Array of structures initialization while doing typedef

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, structure, typedef

Given a structure that represents a point as following:

```
typedef struct p
{
    char c;
    float x,y;
}P[2];
```

How to define and initialize an array that represents the line with points `A(1,0)` and `B(3,0)`?

In the following code, it says `typedef 'P' is initialized (use typeof instead)`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct p
{
    char c;
    float x,y;
}P[2]={{'A',1.0,2.0},{'B',3.0,4.0}};
int main()

{
    printf("\n %c %f %f",P[0].c,P[0].x,P[0].y);
    printf("\n %c %f %f",P[1].c,P[1].x,P[1].y);
    return 0;
}
```

The following works, but it changes the definition of a structure:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct p
{
    char c;
    float x,y;
}point;
point P[2]={{'A',1.0,2.0},{'B',3.0,4.0}};
int main()

{
    printf("\n %c %f %f",P[0].c,P[0].x,P[0].y);
    printf("\n %c %f %f",P[1].c,P[1].x,P[1].y);
    return 0;
}
```

How to initialize this array without changing the definition of structure:

```
 typedef struct p
{
    char c;
    float x,y;
}P[2];
```

Comment: `typedef` is a type definition, not a variable definition.

Comment: You can not combine a type-alias definition with a variable definition in one go. You either define a type-alias (which is what `typedef` does), or you define a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct p
{
    char c;
    float x,y;
}P[2];

int main( void ) 
{
    P a = { { 'A', 1.0f, 2.0f }, { 'B', 3.0f, 4.0f } };

    printf( "a[0] = { %c, %f, %f }, a[1] = { %c, %f, %f }\n", 
            a[0].c, a[0].x, a[0].y, a[1].c, a[1].x, a[1].y );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a[0] = { A, 1.000000, 2.000000 }, a[1] = { B, 3.000000, 4.000000 }
```

Take into account that typedef does not define an object. It defines an alias for a type.

In the shown program the typedef defines name `P` as an alias for type `struct p[2]`.

So instead of writing for example

```
struct p a[2];
```

you can just write

```
P a;
```

Answer (score 2):

As per `C11`, chapter §6.7.8/p3, Type definitions, (*emphasis mine*)

> In a declaration whose storage-class specifier is `typedef`, each declarator defines an
>   identifier to be a typedef name **that denotes the type specified for the identifier** [...]

So, in case you write like

```
typedef struct p
{
    char c;
    float x,y;
} X;
```

`X` is not a *variable* that can be initialized, it's a *type*. You need to define a variable of that type, like

```
X y[2] = {0};
```

In your case, if you really want the *type* to  be `P[2]`, you can also do that, like

```
typedef struct p
{
    char c;
    float x,y;
}P[2];
```

and then,

```
P var = {....//initializer list, }
```

and yes, there's no easy shortcut for combining these two into a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` is not a necessary part of the structure definition, in fact you don't need to give the structure name if you need just one variable in your program. A simple definition in your case would be

```
    struct {
        char c;
        float x,y;
    };
```

If you want to initialize just one variable of that type in your whole file, then you can give something like this

```
    struct {
        char c;
        float x,y;
    } point = {'A', 1.0, 2.0};
```

If you want to initialize an array of that struct then you can change `point` to

```
    point[2] = {{'A', 1.0, 2.0}, {'B', 3.0, 4.0}}
```

Now you want to name you structure as `p`, then you struct will be

```
    struct p {
        char c;
        float x,y;
    } point[2] = {{'A', 1.0, 2.0}, {'B', 3.0, 4.0}};
```

Here `point` will be a variable of type `struct p` and is an `array` of size 2

Now, when you add `typedef` to the `struct`, it will start considering at the end you are not declaring variables of type `struct p` but giving an alias name for something related to `struct p`. It could be a pointer type to `struct p` or like in your case it is an array. For example, if I want to create `typedef` of `struct p*`, then I would write

```
    typedef struct p {
        char c;
        float x,y;
    } *point;
```

So I can declare variable of type `struct p*` as `point P`

In your example you have given the struct as

```
    typedef struct p {
        char c;
        float x,y;
    } point[2];
```

Now you can declare variables of type `struct p[2]` as `point P`

As for the initialization you cannot do that at the end of structure definition while you are actually giving the `typedef` at the start. It will consider it as creating a type where a inline kind of structure definition is going on along with it.